# How to get newly updated data only from Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Always getting whole document while any changes found on Firestore. How to get data that are newly updated only?

This is my data:

[image: collections]

I need msg and sendby in order of object(for eg: 2018_09_17_30_40) inside chat on first load and get only the new msg and sendby if data updated
while on get() getting whole document without any order
Note: Code for Android app.

Comment: Show what you have tried till now.

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can create a Chat App using Cloud Firestore and Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Always getting whole document while any changes found on fire store.

The new Cloud Firestore database has different concepts than Firebase real-time database and should not be confused. There are no field-level permissions or access to a document. It's the entire document, or nothing. Cloud Firestore listeners fire on the document level. There is no way to get triggered with just newly updated data in a document.

Seeing your database, I can say that you haven't chosen the right schema by adding those messages under the chat property.

According to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model):

> Cloud Firestore is optimized for storing large collections of small documents.

You should consider create a new collection named `messages` and store each message as a separate document. In the link above, there are examples of how you can achieve that.

Comment: Since this is the way Firestore works, I cannot provide any other solution other than tat but good to hear that I could help you think differently. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can store the last fetched date, and only get the objects with date greater than last updated date.

```
db.collection('groups')
  .where('participants', 'array-contains', 'user123')
  .where('lastUpdated', '>', lastFetchTimestamp)
  .orderBy('lastUpdated', 'desc')
```

Comment: Is "lastUpdated" an intrinsic property available to query? Or do I need to set "lastUpdated" each time I update a document in Firestore to use this query?